# Are all PL-branched coverings from $\mathbb{T}^4$ to $\mathbb{R}P^4$ null-homotopic?

Tags: differential-topology, homotopy-theory, covering-spaces

I can't solve one problem for the course on branched coverings.

Here it goes: I have to show that any PL-branched covering (simply a surjective PL-map with discrete fibers) from $\mathbb{T}^4$ (4-dimensional real torus) to $\mathbb{R}P^4$ has a degree (maximal number of points in a fiber (it is well-defined)) at least $8$.

I have a theorem (of [Berstein and Edmonds, theorem 2.5](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01403169)) that states that any branched covering from $\mathbb{T}^4$ to $S^4$ has a degree of at least $4.$

My attempts so far: I can solve this problem for the case of the maps $f: \mathbb{T}^4\to\mathbb{R}P^4$ such that $f_*:\pi_1(\mathbb{T}^4) \to \pi_1(\mathbb{R}P^4)$ is zero. (Here I can lift the map to $S^4$ and then by multiplicativity of degree I obtain the result).

However, in more general case, I don't have the lifting map. And of course, there are maps $f: \mathbb{T}^4\to\mathbb{R}P^4$ such that $f_*:\pi_1(\mathbb{T}^4) \twoheadrightarrow \pi_1(\mathbb{R}P^4).$ Still, perhaps all those maps are not PL-branched coverings?

Comment: It may be helpful to include the definitions from Dold and Smith, or at least link to a document containing them.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese I've edited the question, I realized that I don't really need general Dold--Smith definition here

Comment: Hint: Any map $f: X\to RP^4$ lifts to a map $g: X\to S^4$. If $deg(g)\ge 4$, what can you say about $deg(f)?$

Comment: @MoisheKohan Sorry, I don't quite understand what type of degree you use here, since $RP^4$ is not orientable and therefore we can't define it using top homology group.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Maybe you use the degree in a sense of my question. Than it is obviously greater than 4 since we can lift a map to another map from torus to $S^4$ that covers original one. (We just need to take a covering space that corresponds to kernel of the map of fundamental groups). Still I don't know how to prove the fact you mentioned

Comment: For completeness, in my comment I forgot to say "any **branched covering** map $f$...": If one omits this assumption, then, of course, not every map lifts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your definition of a (PL) branched covering is wrong. Check your lecture notes for the correct definition or/and talk to your professor.

The correct definition (for maps between compact PL manifolds) is that $f: X^n\to Y^n$ is a **branched covering** if

(1) there exists a (possibly empty) codimension 2 subcomplex $B\subset Y$ with $A:= f^{-1}(B)$ such that the restriction $f|_{X-A}$ is a covering map (to its image).

(2) In a regular neighborhood of  every point $a\in A$ the map $f$ satisfies some further conditions, namely, it is the cone over a branched covering map between links.

It then follows that the preimage of every point in $Y$ is finite. The **degree** of $f$ (as a branched-covering) is then the cardinality of the preimage of (any) point $y\in Y-B$.

**Remark.** 1. By compactness, part (1) is equivalent to the requirement that $f|_{X-A}$ is a local PL homeomorphism.

2. For the purpose of your question, Part (1) will suffice.
3. Branched covering maps can be also defined for maps between noncompact manifolds and in the two other standard categories (TOP and DIFF).

Now, the hint for solving the problem is that you should first prove that if $X$ is orientable and $Y$ is non-orientable, and $f: X\to Y$ is a branched covering, then the image $f_*(\pi_1(X))$ is contained in the orientation-subgroup of $\pi_1(Y)$. (This is false for general surjective PL maps with finite fibers.)  This is as much as I am willing to say, the rest is up to you to figure out.

Comment: Just to be clear, is your claim in the last paragraph only for a branched covering $f$?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Yes, of course